# Infinispan search inheritance search mapping configuration

Tags: hibernate-search, infinispan

I have simple code that test search engine in Infinispan.

```java
public class InifinispanTest {

    private static class DemoA {
        private Long id;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    private static class DemoB extends DemoA {
        private String value;

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SearchMapping mapping = new SearchMapping();
        mapping.entity(DemoB.class).indexed().providedId()
               .property("id", ElementType.METHOD).field();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(org.hibernate.search.Environment.MODEL_MAPPING, mapping);
        properties.put("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider", "ram");
        properties.put("hibernate.search.default.indexmanager", "near-real-time");

        Configuration infinispanConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .indexing()
                .enable()
                .indexLocalOnly(true)
                .withProperties(properties)
                .loaders().passivation(true).addFileCacheStore()
                .build();

        DefaultCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(infinispanConfiguration);

        final Cache<Integer, DemoB> cache = cacheManager.getCache();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            final DemoB demo = new DemoB();
            demo.setId((long) i);

            cache.put(i, demo);
        }

        final SearchManager searchManager = Search.getSearchManager(cache);
        final QueryBuilder queryBuilder = searchManager.buildQueryBuilderForClass(DemoB.class).get();

        final Query query = queryBuilder.keyword().onField("id").matching(1000l).createQuery();

        final CacheQuery query1 = searchManager.getQuery(query, DemoB.class);

        for (Object  result : query1.list()) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see there is a base class DemoA and its subclass DemoB. I would like to do the search by the super class filed id. However this demo code generates `org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to find field id in com.genesis.inifispan.InifinispanTest$DemoB`

I assume that I missed inheritance configuration in Search Mapping configuration, however looking through documentation I found nothing. I would like to have Java based configuration, because I am not able to change entity class in production environment.

Please, can you help me with configuration or direct my in right way reading documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using SearchMapping you should specify the fields like you would with annotations: *id* is a valid field for *DemoA* only, hence the correct mapping looks like:

```java
SearchMapping mapping = new SearchMapping()
   .entity(DemoA.class)
      .property("id", ElementType.METHOD).field()
   .entity(DemoB.class).indexed()
   ;
```

Also note I removed *providedId()* : no longer required in recent Infinispan versions.

I think the SearchMapping should at least warn you, maybe even throw an immediate exception: opening JIRA [HSEARCH-1328](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1328) .

Comment: That configuration allows inheritance. Thanks.

BTW, id=1000 in cache, cause my loop for 10`000 ;-)